# How do two dots in work in path specifications

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

In this example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
int main()
{
    fs::path p = fs::path("..") / ".." / "AppData";//What is it?
    std::cout << "Current path is " << fs::current_path() << '\n'
              << "Canonical path for " << p << " is " << fs::canonical(p) << '\n';
}
```

What is `".."`, and how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.. is parent directory, if you are in /home/user/kat and go to .. you will be in /home/user.

For example such code:

```
fs::path parentPath = fs::current_path() / "..";
std::cout << parentPath << " → " << fs::canonical(parentPath) << std::endl;
```

Will produce this output (on my PC):

```
"/home/kamil/Pulpit/build/.." → "/home/kamil/Pulpit"
```